# Seemingly random return values

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a simple assembler for a very simple MIPS processer. Unfortunately, C has been giving me a lot of trouble, specifically, `strcasecmp` has not been returning valid/correct results. The results are correct sometimes.. but usually not, and I can't grasp why in the world this would be the case. Beyond any suggestions for a fix, could someone explain why these errors are occurring?

**NOTE** I do not think the error is due to passing the register table. Same errors occur when register table is declared inside the convert register function

Thanks!!!

**the function that should return the value corresponding to the register name. Note that `RegisterTable` is declared in `main`. I did this so I could iterate through and test every Register name in the table from `main`**

```
int ConvertRegisterName(char * rname,REG_NAME_PAIR RegisterTable[32])
{
    int i;
    int j=0;
    for (i=1; i<32; i++,i++)
    {
        if (!(strcasecmp(RegisterTable[i].reg_number,rname) & strcasecmp(RegisterTable[i].reg_name,rname)))
        {
            j=i;
            return j;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!j)
    {
        printf("Error with register name \n");
        return j;
    }
}
```

**The `main` function**

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    REG_NAME_PAIR RegisterTable[32];
    RegisterTable[1].reg_name    = "at";
    RegisterTable[1].reg_number  = "$1";
    RegisterTable[2].reg_name    = "v0";
    RegisterTable[2].reg_number  = "$2";
    RegisterTable[3].reg_name    = "v1";
    RegisterTable[3].reg_number  = "$3";
    RegisterTable[4].reg_name    = "a0";
    RegisterTable[4].reg_number  = "$4";
    RegisterTable[5].reg_name    = "a1";
    RegisterTable[5].reg_number  = "$5";
    RegisterTable[6].reg_name    = "a2";
    RegisterTable[6].reg_number  = "$6";
    RegisterTable[7].reg_name    = "a3";
    RegisterTable[7].reg_number  = "$7";
    RegisterTable[8].reg_name    = "t0";
    RegisterTable[8].reg_number  = "$8";
    RegisterTable[9].reg_name    = "t1";
    RegisterTable[9].reg_number  = "$9";
    RegisterTable[10].reg_name   = "t2";
    RegisterTable[10].reg_number = "$10";
    RegisterTable[11].reg_name   = "t3";
    RegisterTable[11].reg_number = "$11";
    RegisterTable[12].reg_name   = "t4";
    RegisterTable[12].reg_number = "$12";
    RegisterTable[13].reg_name   = "t5";
    RegisterTable[13].reg_number = "$13";
    RegisterTable[14].reg_name   = "t6";
    RegisterTable[14].reg_number = "$14";
    RegisterTable[15].reg_name   = "t7";
    RegisterTable[15].reg_number = "$15";
    RegisterTable[16].reg_name   = "s0";
    RegisterTable[16].reg_number = "$16";
    RegisterTable[17].reg_name   = "s1";
    RegisterTable[17].reg_number = "$17";
    RegisterTable[18].reg_name   = "s2";
    RegisterTable[18].reg_number = "$18";
    RegisterTable[19].reg_name   = "s3";
    RegisterTable[19].reg_number = "$19";
    RegisterTable[20].reg_name   = "s4";
    RegisterTable[20].reg_number = "$20";
    RegisterTable[21].reg_name   = "s5";
    RegisterTable[21].reg_number = "$21";
    RegisterTable[22].reg_name   = "s6";
    RegisterTable[22].reg_number = "$22";
    RegisterTable[23].reg_name   = "s7";
    RegisterTable[23].reg_number = "$23";
    RegisterTable[24].reg_name   = "t8";
    RegisterTable[24].reg_number = "$24";
    RegisterTable[25].reg_name   = "t9";
    RegisterTable[25].reg_number = "$25";
    RegisterTable[26].reg_name   = "k0";
    RegisterTable[26].reg_number = "$26";
    RegisterTable[27].reg_name   = "k1";
    RegisterTable[27].reg_number = "$27";
    RegisterTable[28].reg_name   = "gp";
    RegisterTable[28].reg_number = "$28";
    RegisterTable[29].reg_name   = "sp";
    RegisterTable[29].reg_number = "$29";
    RegisterTable[30].reg_name   = "fp";
    RegisterTable[30].reg_number = "$30";
    RegisterTable[31].reg_name   = "ra";
    RegisterTable[31].reg_number = "$31";


    int i;
    for (i=1; i<32; i++)
    {
        printf("i is %d\n",i);
        printf("Register Name is %s \n" ,RegisterTable[i].reg_name);
        printf("this is the return value %d",ConvertRegisterName(RegisterTable[i].reg_name,RegisterTable));
        printf("\n");
        printf("Register Number %s\n",RegisterTable[i].reg_number);
        printf("this is the return value %d",ConvertRegisterName(RegisterTable[i].reg_number,RegisterTable));
        printf("\n");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

**The `REG_NAME_PAIR` struct**

```
typedef struct
{
    char *reg_name;
    char *reg_number;
} REG_NAME_PAIR;
```

Comment: Do you mean to say `i++, i++`?

Comment: Did you really mean to use & (bit wise and)  rather than &&

Comment: This code is totally confused. Why are you comparing the same "name" argument with `reg_name` *and* also with `reg_number`?

Comment: Code is for humans (especially since you post it here). Please, format accordingly

Answer (score 3):

The conversion function could probably be simplified and corrected to something like this:

```
int ConvertRegisterDesc(const char * token, REG_NAME_PAIR RegisterTable[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i != 32; ++i)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(RegisterTable[i].reg_number, token) == 0 ||
            strcasecmp(RegisterTable[i].reg_name,   token) == 0   )
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

   printf("Error with register name \n");
   return 0;
}
```

Now `ConvertRegisterDesc("foo", RegisterTable)` returns the index of an entry whose name **or** value is (a case variant of) `"foo"`, and `0` if no such entry could be found.

Comment: You don't need the `!` when you explicitly compare the result of `strcasecmp()` with zero, do you?  You're going to return the first register that doesn't match something - and no string is going to match both the number and the name.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the `&` operator instead of `&&`.
`&` does bitwise and, not logical and. So for example:
`0x01 & 0x02 == 0` - because no bit is set on both
`0x01 && 0x02 == 1` - because both 0x01 and 0x02 evaluate to true.